# AggregateException : One or more errors occured. ( Can not resolve scoped Type )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to seed my Identity database with a static class.

Here is my seed method:

```
public static async Task CreateIdentityUsers(IServiceProvider service,IConfiguration configuration)
        {


            var userManager = service.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AlGecUser>>();
            var roleManager = service.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AlGecRole>>();

            var username = configuration["Data:AdminUser:username"];
            var email = configuration["Data:AdminUser:email"];
            var password = configuration["Data:AdminUser:password"];
            var role = configuration["Data:AdminUser:role"];

            if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username) == null)
            {
                if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role) == null)
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new AlGecRole(role));
                }

                AlGecUser user = new AlGecUser()
                {
                    UserName = username,
                    Email = email,
                    Name = "SampleName",
                    Surname = "SampleSurname"
                };

                IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
                }

            }

        }
```

On startup I call this method Like this :

```
 SeedIdentity.CreateIdentityUsers(app.ApplicationServices, Configuration).Wait();
```

Here is my Startup method :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AlGecDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainRepositoryCS")));
        services.AddDbContext<AlGecIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityRepositoryCS")));

        services.AddIdentity<AlGecUser,AlGecRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AlGecIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EfProductRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, EfUnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IAdvertisementRepository, EfAdvertisementRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ICategoryRepository, EfCategoryRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ISubCategoryRepository, EfSubCategoryRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ICartService, CartService>();
        services.AddTransient<ICartSessionService, CartSessionService>();
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    SeedIdentity.CreateIdentityUsers(app.ApplicationServices, Configuration).Wait();
}
```

But while I'm trying to open my web site it throws an error called

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot resolve scoped service 
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AlGec.ECommerce.WebUI.IdentityCore.AlGecUser]' from root provider.)

How can Ifix it?

Comment: You don't show the startup method but it looks like you call this method before the dependency injection container is initialized.

Comment: I'm calling it at the bottom, after everything called.

Comment: Well, you need to show the startup method anyway. We have nothing to go by.

Comment: I posted it. thnks for trying to help me out.

Comment: And what about `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: updated and added.

Answer (score 0):

Your seed data should not be added through the startup but rather the `ef migrations` command. Let it do the job it was intended to do. If you need to ensure data exists on start up, look into running the migrations at startup.